# How can I publish library from dist directory saving node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, publish

I want to publish npm package and have next type of import:
`import { Component } from "my-lybrary/Component"`

I found out that I have to copy my package.json to dist directory and run `npm publish ./dist`. Well, it works, but final package doesn't have directory node_modules, that I have in dist after building. How can I save node_modules directory?

1. I tried to add !node_modules/ at .npmignore
2. I tried to publish from root directory (my package.json has `files: ["dist"]`, but in this case I have incorrect structure:

- my-lybrary
  --dist
  ----component

instead of

- my-lybrary
  --component

Comment: The `node_modules` folder should never be uploaded to npm. Instead, the dependencies of the project should be added to the `dependencies` or `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` of the library. How are you building the library? Are you using ng-packagr?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing `node_modules` within your package isn't typical or recommended due to potential bloat and dependency conflicts. Instead, list your dependencies in `package.json`. Consumers installing your package will have these dependencies resolved automatically. If you need specific modules within your package, consider bundling them into your distribution files using tools like Webpack or Rollup. This way, you maintain a clean package structure and prevent issues related to directly including `node_modules`.